# How to avoid the repeated execution of setenv in lua script

Tags: lua, setenv

I have two running environment in lua script.One is the biggest power and another one is limited.

How to isolate running environment.I use lua5.1 and I also know using setenv function.

But I want to avoid the repeated execution of setenv in every function execution.

Here is an example.

```
function SpawnSandBox( )

    local SandBoxGlobals = {}

    SandBoxGlobals.print             = print
    SandBoxGlobals.table             = table
    SandBoxGlobals.string             = string     
    SandBoxGlobals.math               = math 
    SandBoxGlobals.assert             = assert 
    SandBoxGlobals.getmetatable    = getmetatable 
    SandBoxGlobals.ipairs             = ipairs 
    SandBoxGlobals.pairs             = pairs 
    SandBoxGlobals.pcall             = pcall 
    SandBoxGlobals.setmetatable    = setmetatable 
    SandBoxGlobals.tostring        = tostring 
    SandBoxGlobals.tonumber        = tonumber 
    SandBoxGlobals.type            = type 
    SandBoxGlobals.unpack             = unpack 
    SandBoxGlobals.collectgarbage     = collectgarbage
    SandBoxGlobals._G                = SandBoxGlobals

    return SandBoxGlobals
end

function ExecuteInSandBox( SandBox, Script )

    local ScriptFunc, CompileError = loadstring( Script )

    if CompileError then
        return CompileError
    end

    setfenv( ScriptFunc, SandBox )

    local Result, RuntimeError = pcall( ScriptFunc )
    if RuntimeError then
        return RuntimeError
    end

    return nil
end


local SandBox = SpawnSandBox( )


print ( "Response=", ExecuteInSandBox( SandBox, "table.foreach( _G, print )" ) )
```

Comment: Are you routinely calling `ExecuteInSandbox` with the same `Script` contents? Or are the contents there always changing?

Comment: with the same Script contents

Comment: Just so you know, you can do `math.floor = function() print("I'm evil") end` and it will break out of the sandbox. You need to copy the library tables.

Comment: @Colonel Thirty Two,I know your mean,but if I don't put math in my table, you define function will run error.

Comment: @gougou: Why do you want to avoid the repeated execution of `setfenv`? It certainly isn't performance critical as it only changes a single pointer (after some type checking). I'd rather suggest caching/memoizing the result of `loadstring` ...

Comment: @siffiejoe: yes,I have cache the result of loadfile,It works.If there are some ways to cache setfenv,it will be better.

Comment: @gougou: You can always cache by input string _and_ sandbox -- you just need a 2 dimensional table structure. But I doubt that this will buy you much in runtime speed (and it will cost memory).

Comment: @siffiejoe:you can see this details in https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-lrucache/

Comment: @gougou: According to Github search there isn't any `setfenv` or `loadstring` in the whole repository. Are you sure that is the correct link?

Comment: @siffiejoe：https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-lrucache,you can search key word lua-resty-lrucache.